# How do I resize an imageview image in javafx?

Tags: java, image, javafx, resize, imageview

I need to resize an image to specific dimensions, 100 by 100 pixels for example, in JavaFX.

How can I achieve that? Could the Image or the ImageView class be used for this purpose?

Comment: This question should not have been closed as too broad.  The question is specific to JavaFX.  The question is concise, clear and useful.  Nobody who voted to close this question has ever answered a JavaFX question.  I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Yes, using an [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html). Just call

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView("...");
imageView.setFitHeight(100);
imageView.setFitWidth(100);
```

By default, it will not preserve the `width:height` ratio: you can make it do so with

```
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
```

Alternately you can resize the [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) directly on loading:

```
Image image = new Image("my/res/flower.png", 100, 100, false, false);
```

Resizing the image on loading is useful for things like thumbnails of larger images as the memory required is lower than storing the larger image data representation in memory.

Comment: Does it make sense that this works for me only for shrinking and not for enlarging? Maybe I'm missing something in the docs

Comment: @eliblanco87 you will probably get an out of bounds exception if you try to preserve the ratio for enlarging, if you set this to false it will work.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done in FXML (if using it) like this  :

```
<ImageView>
  <fitWidth>100</fitWidth>
  <preserveRatio>true</preserveRatio>
   <image>
      <Image url="@images/icon2.png"/>
   </image>
</ImageView>
```