# Optimal solution for Image scaling where i need to preserve aspect ratio and retain good quality

Tags: java, javafx

So here is the problem: I am loading an image which is of unknown resolution. I need to scale it to 500px width to fit within my UI, preserving aspect ratio. The image quality must be good as i need to use it later, specifically to calculate an angle between two objects within the image.

So far i have tried the following:

> In the following examples, we have an existing UI element `ImageView imageView;`

Method one: using scale on load in JavaFX image constructor:

```
public void setImage(String path){
    Image image = new Image(path, 550, 412, true, true);
    imageView.setImage(image);
}
```

This method achieves the required scaling, but lacks the quality required for an accurate calculation of angle later on.

Method two: using ImageView scaling to scale the displayed image:

```
public void setImage(String path){
    Image image = new Image(path);
    imageView.setFitWidth(550);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageView.setImage(image);
}
```

This achieves the required quality and scaling, but the image *contained* within the view is not actually scaled, which means the calculations done later down the line are using an image not representative of the one being displayed.

Is there a way i can alter either of these solutions to work better or is there a better approach i can take? thank you.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894945/how-do-i-resize-an-imageview-image-in-javafx. You probably don't want to smooth the image, so set change the constructor `new Image(path, 550, 412, true, false);`

Comment: @SME_Dev I'm unsure how this is a duplicate if I've detailed the solutions in that answer in my post, stating they both have issues for me. And I don't understand what you mean by using the wrong Boolean flags. my understanding was that i have set preserve ration to true as well as choosing a higher quality processing algorithm?

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: I have just tried the code you're using with an image I have and I notice no visual difference in quality between the `ImageView` and the `Image`. Until you [edit] your question and include a [mcve], as already requested, and the image you're using, as well a screenshot of where you see the lower quality, there's really nothing more we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use,

```
imageView.setSmooth(true);
```

to achieve better quality image after scaling.

**EDIT:**

It is because, the two methods are essentially different. The first method loads a bad quality image in the first place (with lesser pixels). One thing you can try is, to use AWT Image class for loading the image, using `ImageIO`, and call `scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(width, height)`. Then use something like (pseudo code):

1. create bufferedImage of scaled size
2. `bufferedImage.createGraphics()
     .drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, null)`

to get scaled AWT Image. Then use SwingFXUtils to convert to image for FX application. This whole thing can probably be done in 3 lines of code by chaining the methods. I was able to achieve better quality this way in one of my previous projects.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the issue of quality was not present when i scale using the imageView, it looks as i would like. The problem occurs in the first method where i set the scaling within the image constructor. I tried using your solution but the quality is still not as good as achieved in method two.