# Image view size not respected in JavaFX tab pane dropdown

Tags: javafx

I'm using a JavaFX TabPane with an image set for one of my tabs. The actual image is bigger than it needs to be, so I use `ImageView.setFitHeight(int)` and `ImageView.setFitWidth(int)` to change the image size.

It looks fine in the tab label itself, but when I add too many tabs and the tab drop down is added, the size in the dropdown is displayed in the original image size. Any ideas of how to change the image size in the dropdown?

Minimum reproducible example:

```java
public class TabGraphicsIssueDemo extends Application {

    private static final int TAB_IMAGE_SIZE = 15;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        
        TabPane pane = new TabPane();
        
        ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("smile.jpg")));
        image.setFitHeight(TAB_IMAGE_SIZE);
        image.setFitWidth(TAB_IMAGE_SIZE);
        
        Tab imageTab = new Tab();
        imageTab.setGraphic(image);
        pane.getTabs().add(imageTab);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pane.getTabs().add(new Tab("Tab " + i));
        }
        
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That looks like a bug. A couple of suggestions (neither of which I have tested, yet): 1. [Resize the image on loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894945/how-do-i-resize-an-imageview-image-in-javafx/27894962#27894962), or 2. Wrap the image view in a pane which sizes it, and make the pane the graphic.

Comment: Awesome @James_D, thanks for the quick response! Resizing the image on loading worked for me. I didn't try wrapping it in a pane, but I bet that would work too. I'll go ahead and write an answer with that and accept it, unless you'd like to post it as an answer yourself to boost your slack street cred.
I'll also report it as a bug.

Comment: Actually, when I tried wrapping it in the pane, it didn't show up at all in the dropdown. I'm not really sure how that works anyway: the same node can't appear twice in the scene graph, so it's hard to see how they made that happen, unless it's a snapshot.

Comment: Hmm yes. The dropdown only supports `Label` and `ImageView` as a graphic, and reproduces them in a [very hacky](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/TabPaneSkin.java#L483) way. It creates a new `ImageView` with the same image, but doesn't copy other properties (such as `fitHeight` and `fitWidth` over.

Comment: Haha, at least in their comment they acknowledge that its hacky :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation in the current version (JavaFX version 17) replicates `Label`s and `ImageView`s (so they can appear both in the tab and the tabs menu) in a fairly primitive way. If the graphic for a `Tab` is an `ImageView`, a new `ImageView` is created with its `ImageProperty` bound to the original `ImageView`'s `imageProperty`. However, other properties, such as `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` are not copied.

So a workaround is to resize the `Image` instead of the `ImageView`. This means the `ImageView` used by the tabs menu will reference the resized `Image` as well, and doesn't need `fitHeight` and `fitWidth` set:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TabPane pane = new TabPane();

        ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("smile.jpg"),
                                      TAB_IMAGE_SIZE, TAB_IMAGE_SIZE, true, true));

//        image.setFitHeight(TAB_IMAGE_SIZE);
//        image.setFitWidth(TAB_IMAGE_SIZE);


        Tab imageTab = new Tab();
        imageTab.setGraphic(image);
        pane.getTabs().add(imageTab);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pane.getTabs().add(new Tab("Tab " + i));
        }


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```